# WordPress running code from template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have discovered that WordPress is executing code from a template that is in my theme, but when it is not actually on a page using the template.

Although this template will not be used in a live state (since it only runs a loop to create data) I was wondering if anyone else had come across this - and besides shoving everything in functions.php, how to get WP to stop including/running the template when the site load?

I am presuming the reason the code is run, is when WP loads and is looking for templates etc is actual includes(); the template file at some point? which causes the loop to run? if this is the case, does this mean any php in any template file is run?

Here is the code from a the template that is being included (excluding the WP template header) The this code is being run on any page that hasn't got the template set. `get_base_question_meta` is a function which returns an pre-built array.

```
$users = get_users( array() );
$base_meta = get_base_question_meta();    
$new_meta = array();

foreach ($users as $user ){    
    if($user->data->ID == 1){
        continue;
    }       
    foreach ($base_meta as $question_group_id => $question_groups){     
        foreach ( $question_groups as $group_id => $sets ){     
            foreach ($sets as $set_id => $set ){
                foreach ($set as $question_id => $question ){
                    $new_meta[ $group_id ][ $set_id ][ $question_id ]  = (string)rand(1, 5);
                }
            }
        }       
    }    
    update_user_meta($user->data->ID, 'saved_answers', $new_meta);      
}
```

Comment: updated my post =) wasn't sure if it was going to be helpful, sorry!

Comment: The problem is not in this block of code. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11760129/1287812) may help.