# Most productive (Effective-efficient) way to find php code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am modifying someone else´s theme. The way I am doing it is looking for the source code to find where it is located and modify it. I am using grep to find the html ids and classes on the theme folder. It takes sometime and I am not sure if there is a better way.

Is it there any other way on locating/modifying code in wordpress?

ps: I am using a child theme for the changes.

Comment: Good IDE should make wonders for you.

Comment: Interesting! Which one do you recommend?

Comment: PHPStorm is my IDE of choice. Maybe it'll be pricey for you, but worth every penny.

Comment: also look in template hierarchy https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy it faster when you understand the whole concept behind theme files structure (see graph)

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9405896